Does PowerQuery/PowerBI OData Feed cache and utilize ETag/if-none-match headers?
If an OData source provides an ETag header, will PowerBI use that in an if-none-match header when a data refresh happens with a HTTP 304?
I'm trying to design a system that allows for as frequent as desired updates to happen in PowerBI while the server can gracefully 304 them when no changes have occurred. What I have in mind is a system that keeps changes tracked, rather than needing a query over a large database for each request. But, if PowerBI is not going to send a if-none-match header and accept HTTP 304, then I'm not going to get a performance benefit from that.
I've searched all over and found this page which has some reference to caching ("ExcludedFromCacheKey" parameter), but it is unclear how/if this relates to ETag, if-none-match, and HTTP 304.
I'm hoping someone has an OData API set up being queried via PowerBI that can look at the logs and see if PowerBI is sending if-none-match headers.
